# Как реализовать метод void incl(double)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, c++11, методы

Множество вещественных чисел

```
class ASet
{
  public:
    ASet(int size); // size - максимальное количество чисел в множестве
    ~ASet();
    void incl(double x);  // включить число в множество, 
                     // если такое число уже есть, то ничего не делать
    void excl(double x);  // исключить
    bool contain(double x); // содержится в множестве?
    void print(); // распечатать состояние объекта
};
```

Comment: А нам тем более это не понятно, так как не ясно, как реализован ваш класс.

Comment: Класс должен иметь поле со множеством это во первых, во вторых метод excl() должна принимать double? Тут или порядковый номер числа во множестве или double и кидать исключение. Если вы переделаете свой класс я думаю вам будет очевидно как исключать число. Советую сразу сделать заменить конструктор на ASet() и использовать std::vector

Comment: если и дальше будет не понятно что нибудь напишу.

Comment: Так а что должно быть "под капотом" вашего `ASet`? Простой массив, или `std::vector`, или `std::set`, или красно-черное дерево, или ...?

Comment: "под капотом"  ASet  должен быть простой массив

Comment: Рекомендую сразу сделать вектор иначе надо каждый раз заного выделять память и каждый раз делать коптю из одного массива в другой

Comment: @maks makarov Возникает естественный вопрос: должны ли данные в массиве храниться в отсортированном порядке или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные могут храниться в неупорядочном виде, то реализация метода `incl` может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано ниже в упрощенной демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class ASet
{
public:
    ASet( size_t size ); // size - максимальное количество чисел в множестве
    ~ASet();
    void incl(double x);  // включить число в множество, 
                     // если такое число уже есть, то ничего не делать
    void print() const; // распечатать состояние объекта
private:
    size_t n;
    size_t pos;
    double *p;
};

ASet::ASet( size_t size ) : n( size ), pos( 0 ), p( new double[n] )
{
}

ASet::~ASet()
{
    delete [] p;
}

void ASet::incl( double x )
{
    if ( pos != n && std::find( p, p + pos, x ) == p + pos )
    {
        p[pos++] = x;
    }
}

void ASet::print() const
{
    std::copy( p, p + pos, std::ostream_iterator<double>( std::cout, " " ) );   
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    ASet set( N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        set.incl( i );
        set.print();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Жаль что человеку будет лень разьираться ) и ему нужно это что бы сдать лабу. Но плюсик я поставил)

Comment: @jNX С другой стороны, утешает, что за всякие `std::copy( p, p + pos, std::ostream_iterator<double>( std::cout, " " ) );` на лабе ТСу точно влетит. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это точно) Хотя я бы порофлил с ответа

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да даже тут мне кажется `ASet::pos != ASet::n && std::find( p, p + pos, x ) == p + pos`, человек который не может такую функцию написать сознание потеряет и забросит нафиг с++

Comment: @jNX вроде бы всё просто и понятно. Вот зачем только :: нужны, с ними красивее код не становится

Comment: @pavel В данной реализации простой функции это излишне. А в общем случае тело методов может быть очень большим, и тогда сложно уследить, какие идентификаторы относятся к членам класса, а какин - к локадльным переменным.

Comment: @pavel это вам и мне понятно а человеку который такой метод написать не может я думаю не совсем очевидно

Comment: @pavel, зато понятно что вызывается именно функция из стандартной библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Например так.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ASet
{
    static const int MAX_C = 1000003;
    char isSet[MAX_C];
    size_t hash(double x){
       return std::hash<double>()(x) % MAX_C;
    } 
  public:
    void incl(double x){
        isSet[hash(x)] = 1;
    }
    void excl(double x){
        isSet[hash(x)] = 0;
    }
    bool contain(double x){
        return isSet[hash(x)];

    }
};
int main() {
    int N = 5;
    ASet set;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        set.incl( i );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N+2; i++ )
        cout << set.contain( i )<<" ";
       cout << endl;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        set.excl( i );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N+2; i++ )
        cout << set.contain( i )<<" ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод.

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```